# How to fix (no instance of overloaded function " getline" matches the argument list) in my code

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm getting two errors in my code that I have been stuck in for a while.
I'm trying to fix the "no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list" error.
Also getting the error: identifier "buffer" is undefined.

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    class City
    {
        char name[12];

    public:

        City(char input[])
        {
            strcpy_s(name, input);
        }

        char* getName()
        {
            return name;

        }
        string  buffer;
    };

    int main(void)
    {
        char place[] = "Cambridge";

        // Create object file pointer for reading
        ifstream inFile;

        // Define variable for data to be read from file
        string line;

        // Connect to file for reading
        inFile.open("testfile.txt");

        if (inFile.is_open() == false)
            cout << "Error opening file\n" << endl;
        else
        {
            while (getline(inFile, line))
            {
                cout << line;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "What's the city name?" << endl;

        getline(cin, buffer);

        inFile.close();
        system("pause");
        return 0;


    }
```

My aim is for the code to ask the user for input. After the user inputs a city name it should get saved into the "testfile.txt".

Comment: Why have you declared a `City` class if you don't use it? Also, you haven't declared a `buffer`. Did you mean to create a city object and then access the `buffer` from it?

Comment: There is a member variable named `buffer` in the class `City` but there is no such variable in `main`. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.